# performance difference between cli and apache cgi mode for php

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface

I've found significant performance difference between php cli and cgi mode:

cli:

```
set : 1.853 seconds 54 qps
get : 2.226 seconds 45 qps
incr : 1.577 seconds 63 qps
```

cgi:

```
set : 1.063 seconds 94 qps 
get : 0.829 seconds 121 qps
incr : 1.037 seconds 96 qp
```

Is it coincident? Or is there a reason for that difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider when you are using php as a apache module, when someone hit your web server an apache process is created which has php in it and apache process calls php.
so one main difference is when you execute a php script in cli mode you call php directly but when using apache first you call apache and apache has itself initializations and after that it calls php and also after that php gives back the result to apache and then apache returns the result to http client which has hit the server.

Comment: This sounds a little subjective. I am not sure.

Comment: I can't think of any other differences.
because in both cases php compiler and executer is the same.

Comment: mhndev is true, overhead of apache is the reason of this

Comment: @MrezaJafari However apache version runs faster, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Consider even that maybe PHP via Apache has OpCache enabled and this can boost dramatically your script performance.
In my scenario, a PHP script that calls a radius integration runs via CLI at 100ms.
With a CURL towards apache to the same script, runs in 25ms.
Another cause of performance boost could be that you run PHP-FPM with STATIC pools.
This reduces the time for Apache to call and fork a new PHP process to run your script.
This could be critical in an environment within thousands of calls to the same script as mine.